# Greater, Less than or equal in Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am really a beginner in assembly language. I have very little knowledge of the syntax. I was studying it on the web but I can't understand it very well. I found a sample problem to experiment on but can't really understand how to do it.

here's the problem

You are given two strings of characters, which we shall refer to as A and B.  A is at most 5 characters long and B at most 255 characters long.  Write an assembly language program which will count the number of occurrences of the string A in the string B, leaving the result to AL.  Thus, if A were the string “job” and B were the string “job I got a job” your program should leave 2 in AL.

so far I can only do print out and display strings. how do I solve the problem that involves math logic?

```
if AL > 7, display “Greater than Seven!”,
if AL < 7, display “Less than Seven!”,
if AL = 7, display “Equal to Seven!”.
```

Edit:

I have a sample code but only for characters. how do I replace it to string?

```
DATA SEGMENT
   MSG1 DB 10,13, 'ENTER ANY STRING : - $'
   MSG2 DB 10,13, 'ENTER ANY CHARACTER : -$'
   MSG3 DB 10,13, ' $'
   MSG4 DB 10,13, 'NO CHARACTER FOUND IN THE GIVEN STRING $'
   MSG5 DB ' CHARACTER(S) FOUND IN THE GIVEN STRING $'
   CHAR DB ?
   COUNT DB 0
   P1 LABEL BYTE
   M1 DB OFFH
   L1 DB ?
   P11 DB OFFH DUP ('$')

DATA ENDS
DISPLAY MACRO MSG
   MOV AH, 9
   LEA DX, MSG
   INT 21H
ENDM

CODE SEGMENT
   ASSUME CS:COD,DS:DATA
START:
      MOV AX,DATA
      MOV DS,AX

      DISPLAY MSG1

      LEA DX,P1
      MOV AH,0AH
      INT 21H

      DISPLAY MSG2

      MOV AH,1
      INT 21H
      MOV CHAR,AL

      DISPLAY MSG3

      LEA SI, P11

      MOV CL,L1
      MOV CH,0
CHECK:
      MOV AL,[SI]
      CMP CHAR,AL
      JNE SKIP
      INC COUNT
SKIP:
      INC SI
      LOOP CHECK

      CMP COUNT, 0
      JE NOTFOUND

      DISPLAY MSG3

      MOV DL,COUNT
      ADD DL,30H
      MOV AH,2
      INT 21H

      DISPLAY MSG5
      JMP EXIT
NOT FOUND:
          DISPLAY MSG4
EXIT:   MOV AH, 4CH
        INT 21H

CODE ENDS
END START
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to program a string search, in assembly. There are many ways to do that. Suggest you start with the naive string search https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: (assuming x86/64) A CMP (compare) instruction will set various flags in the flags register..you can then use conditional-instructions, whose behavior depends on the flags. Obvious (not efficient) examples are the conditional jumps: jz (jump-if-zero), jnz (jump-if-not-zero), ja (jump-if-above), jb (jump-if-below), jl (jump-if-less), jg (jump-if-greater) etc. There are also conditional-MOVes.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to do this would be to search for the first character of A in B, using

```
        repne   scasb
```

if you find a match, then you can do a string compare of A and the current spot in B using.

```
        repe    cmpsb
```

I'm assuming you have a guide that will explain how the registers are used by these instructions.

There's a somewhat faster method to search for a single character in a string, using a register with 4 (or 8) bytes with the same value in a loop, but it's overly complicated for this example program.

Comment: JFYI, there are even more efficient algorithms for searching substring in text, using pre-calculated table to advance trough text B often by full length of A (per compare). But the pre-calculation takes some time (maybe not worth for max 255 of B), and also this task is mostly memory I/O limited, so performance gain by advancing by length of A is probably not that huge (and again limit of 5 for A is probably under the threshold where it makes sense, the 8 bytes vectorized first char check will probably beat that). Did check the wiki above, the one I'm talking about is "Boyer–Moore".